# Posting single and collection of objects to the same endpoint in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I'm looking for a way to have the same endpoint (in ASP.NET Core 2.0) accepting single as well as a collection but can't figure out how to make it work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] SampleModel model)
    {
        return "Single";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] SampleModel[] models)
    {
        return "Multiple";
    }
```

The goal is to make it possible to POST both

```
{
  "name": "Single"
}
```

as well as

```
[
  {
    "name": "Multi1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Multi2"
  }
]
```

to the same endpoint - "api/sample/".

Is this at all possible (by using a Custom Model Binder etc)?

This seems like a nice thing for API to support.

Comment: Try to look for JObject now challenge is to identify object or collection so in that case if your coversion success on object then it's mean object otherwise it's collectino.

Comment: @Parwej Yes, I looked at that as a solution but then you loose all of the model building goodness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a single action that takes a JToken from the body and then call the method you want based on what type you can deserialize the token to.

```
private ActionResult<string> Single(SampleModel model)
{
  return "Single";
}

private ActionResult<string> Multiple(SampleModel[] models)
{
  return "Multiple";
}

private bool TryToObject<T>(JToken token, out T value)
{
  try
  {
    value = token.ToObject<T>();
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception) { }
  value = default(T);
  return false;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] JToken token)
{
  if (TryToObject(token, out SampleModel[] models))
    return Multiple(models);
  else if (TryToObject(token, out SampleModel model))
    return Single(model);
  else
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The JToken was the key to the problem! :D